# Approximate of transformations

Tags: linear-transformations, approximation, approximation-theory

I understand that what we need to do in this situation. But, I can not find the exact solution. I found the measure of the arc which is the image of the segment $[0, a]$ but still didn't describe its formula.

Problem: "The upper half-plane is mapped onto the unit disk so that the point $z = hi(h > 0)$ passes into
the center of the circle. Find the length $\Gamma$ of the image of the segment $[0, a]$ of the real axis $(a > 0)$ and obtain linear approximate formulae for $\Gamma$ for small $a/h$ and for small $h/a$."

Comment: I don't think you can do this, unless you know more about the map. Is it supposed to be a fractional linear transformation, for example?

Comment: We can find that this case, the transformation has form $w(z)=e^{i\alpha}\dfrac{z-hi}{z+hi}$ and $w(0)=e^{i(\alpha+\pi)}$, $w(a)=e^{i\alpha}\dfrac{a-hi}{a+hi}$. Thus, $\text{arg}(w(0))=\alpha+\pi$, $\text{arg}(w(a))=\alpha-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{h}{a}\right)$. Therefore the measure of $\Gamma$ equals to $\pi + 2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{h}{a}\right)$ and this is its length because this case radius equals to 1.